# Why is reading from file and storing details in classes providing garbage values?

Tags: java, file, file-handling

Following is the code I am using to read from a file and saving details from it in `ArrayList` of two classes `Iphone` and `Ipad`, but apparently something is going wrong with this.

The output I am getting for this code is:

> Iphone@28d93b30 and IndexOutOfBoundException for `ipads.get(0)`

```java
try {
            fScanner = new Scanner(new File("apple.txt"));
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        ArrayList<Iphone> iphones = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Ipad> ipads = new ArrayList<>();

        while(fScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fScanner.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

            if(lineScanner.next().equals("IPHONE")) {

                    String model = "IPHONE"+lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String scrSze = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String proc = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String simT = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String clr = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String rom = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String is3dtouch = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String pric = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();

                    iphones.add(new Iphone(model,scrSze,proc,simT,clr,rom,is3dtouch,pric)); 

            }


            else if(lineScanner.next().equals("IPAD")) {

                    String model = "IPAD"+lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String scrSze = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String proc = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String iswifi = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String clr = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String memo = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();
                    String pric = lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next();

                    ipads.add(new Ipad(model,scrSze,proc,iswifi,clr,memo,pric));

            }

        }

        System.out.println(iphones.get(2)+"\n");
        System.out.println(ipads.get(0)+"\n");
```

The file is like this:

```text
IPHONE 7, 4.7, A10, GSM, JET BLACK, 32GB, TRUE, 700
IPAD AIR 2, 9.7, A8, TRUE, SILVER, 64GB, 400
IPHONE SE, 4, A9, CDMA, SILVER, 16GB, FALSE, 490
IPAD PRO, 9.7, A9, TRUE, SPACE GREY, 32GB, 650
IPHONE X, 7, A11, LTE, BLACK, 128GB, TRUE, 999
IPAD PRO X, 12, A12, TRUE, SPACE GREY, 256GB, 700
```

I'd appreciate a good explanation of the above problem.

Comment: You need to override the `toString()` method for it to print something useful. I suggest using your iDE to generate this method.

Comment: `Scanner.next()` reads words between whitespace, not the text between `,` by default.  I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `Iphone@28d93b30` because you're printing an Iphone, and you haven't overridden the `toString()` method in the Iphone class, which means that the default `Object.toString()` method is being executed.

You get an exception because you're trying to get the first Ipad in the list, and there isn't any in the list. There isn't any because you're calling `next()` twice (once in the first `if` condition, and once in the second `else if` condition, so the token you're comparing with "IPAD" is the second one of the line, and not the first one.

Comment: You just saved me from typing this out.